# Are these nominalisations?

Tags: nominalizations

I'm having trouble with identifying whether something is a nominalisation or just a regular noun. I would like some help in checking if I'm correct.

"Another problem is the treatment of citizens in our country."

"This is the concern of the citizens."

In these two sentences, "treatment" is a nominalisation, and "concern" is a nominalisation. Is this true?

Comment: If it's a nominalization, you should be able to point out the source it was nominalized from. The noun _concern_, for instance, comes from _concerned_, which is a verb form of _concern_; and the noun _treatment_ comes from the verb _treat_. So both of these nouns are nominalizations, like _nominalization_ itself.

Comment: How does one define a 'regular' noun? It seems rather arbitrary to bestow this qualifier to identify 'a noun that appeared in the lexicon _as_ a noun rather than as a result of morphological derivation'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> If it's a nominalization, you should be able to point out the source it was nominalized from. The noun *concern*, for instance, comes from *concerned*, which is a verb form of *concern*; and the noun *treatment* comes from the verb *treat*. So both of these nouns are nominalizations, like *nominalization* itself.